# Сортировка массива разворотом первых k элементов

Tags: pascal, сортировка, java, c++

Необходим отсортировать входной массив, используя только операции разворота первых k элементов. Необходимо вывести количество таких разворотов и каждое такое k. Расскажите пожалуйста алгоритм действий или приведите пример кода на любом удобном для вас языке. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

алгоритм будет простой, но не сильно быстрый. Кроме разворота части массива, нужна будет функция поиска максимума (или минимума) в первых k элементах.

Так как можно разворачивать только первые элементы, то сортировать массив будем с конца. Итак, алгоритм сортировки будет такой

k - количество "неотсортированных элементов". В самом начале равен количеству элементов в массиве, с каждой интерацией уменьшается на 1. (для удобства, элементы нумеруем с 1).

цикл:

- в диапазоне от 1 до k найти максимальный элемент, пусть это будет элемент с индексом m
- если m не равно 1, то сделать разворот элементов от 1 до m.
- сделать разворот от 1 до k.

когда k будет равно 1 - цикл завершается.

количество разворотов - максимально - (размер массива -1) * 2, минимально - 0 (если массив отсортирован.